# PHP: file_get_contents & curl not working (but terminal curl does)

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I'm trying to curl json from this link: http://web-app.usc.edu/ws/soc/api/departments/20131

I've tried:

file_get_contents:

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://web-app.usc.edu/ws/soc/api/departments/20131");
```

curl:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://web-app.usc.edu/ws/soc/api/departments/20131');
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

But the file_get_contents "fails to open stream" and curl just seems to hang. Interestingly, curl-ing the url in terminal works just fine.

**What's going wrong?**

Answer (score 2):

Php settings can (and should) forbid using file_get_contents, which calls fopen, on urls.  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php.

Curl is the proper way to grab files.  I think your problem might be a missing curl option. Try setting `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to true.  If you don't, then the transfer is output directly rather being the return value of the call to `curl_exec()`.

```
$ch = curl_init('http://web-app.usc.edu/ws/soc/api/departments/20131');
curl_setopt ( $ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true );
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Another RTM link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Could you add a quick explanation of what CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER means? Future visitors will appreciate having all the relevant info in one place

Comment: Lots of things are possible.  :)  But if you know my solution doesn't work, you should edit your question to reflect it.  Can you also post error or access logs from your php script?